# ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types,

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a circular level set function on python. I have an error when I defined this function.
First I create a mesh grid, then I gave the coordinates of the center of the cercle and its radius and later I defined my level set function phi.
The error that I have is when I defined phi : TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
import numpy
xstart, xend = 0.0, 8.0
ystart, yend = 0.0, 8.0
N = 50

x = numpy.linspace(xstart, xend, N)
y = numpy.linspace(ystart, yend, N)
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)

#radius
r = 0.5
#center
xc = 2.0
yc = 1.0

#level set function
phi = numpy.sqrt((X-xc)^2+(Y-yc)^2) - r
```

Comment: Yes, you can't do a bitwise xor (`^` operator) there. Do you mean exponentiation? That's written `**` in Python.